# Identifying geometric shapes in matrix using algebraic constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, graph-theory, linear-programming

I'm currently studying topology for my thesis. The problem I'm having now is identifying geometric shapes (e.g. rectangles) in a grid (see image). At this point I'm trying to keep it as mathematical as possible instead of defining computational functions.

The situation is as follows: Assume a $N \times N$ grid which represents a space. The grid can be represented as a matrix $S$. The cells in the grid are numbered and stored in a table with each cell having its specific properties. From this grid a graph $G(V,E)$ is created using Von Neumann neighbourhoods to determine connectivity between the cells. From $G(V,E)$ an adjacency matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is created.

Now let's assume a rectangle has to be modelled in the grid. A rectangle is in fact a vector with $0$ if the cell is not part of the rectangle or $1$ if it is. This results in a vector $\mathbf{v}$ of length $N \times N$ which stores $1$ on the indices which together form a rectangle on the grid.

The hard part is the formulation (detection) of a rectangle in a grid: when is a rasterized rectangle a rectangle? I can create computational functions which can draw (rasterize) rectangles in programming. Many image processing libraries are available to draw shapes in an image, which can be interpreted as a grid. However, I want to define a rectangle using algebraic constraints. My question is: is there a set of algebraic constraints which can formulate a rectangle in a grid? the rectangle doe not have an exact rectangle, but is rectangle-like.

[image: 1]

I tried defining a few constraints. For example, a rectangle has an area of $x$ blocks, thus the sum of the indices in the vector should be $x$ (i.e. $\sum v =x$).

Another constraint I thought of was the area-to-perimeter ratio of a rectangle. The perimeter can be found by the dot product of $Av$ and the indices which have less than $4$ neighbours are set to be the perimeter.  From that your pre-defined rectangle ratio can be found by counting perimeter blocks and all the $1$'s in the vector.

Any answer, literature, or tutorial is welcome! I'm a bit of a math newbie so if anything is unclear let me know!

Comment: I don't understand the question clearly yet but I have a feeling that you want to detect a rectangle-like shape in a raster/image and measure the extent to which it can be considered a rectangle. Is that so?

Comment: Yes, you are right!